# HTML multiple Javascript alias

Tags: javascript, html, ip-camera

I'm trying to import the image of multiple IP cameras into one page. However, the script the camera serves for the viewer has the same name on every camera so i cannot seem to display both the viewers on one page. Would it be possible to import the scripts with a sort of AS alias so it knows which of the 2 scripts to execute?

In the below pseudo-code I show what i exactly mean (i made up the AS="cam1" and the cam1.~~)

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Security Cameras</title>
</head>
<body>
        <script AS="cam1" type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.10:80/jsv/SncViewer.js'></script><script>cam1.SNC.writeViewer({sz:'4',ptz:'1',fps:'15',iPS:'1'})</script>
        <script AS="cam2" type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.20:80/jsv/SncViewer.js'></script><script>cam2.SNC.writeViewer({sz:'4',ptz:'1',fps:'15',iPS:'1'})</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to setup individual html page for each camera script, and load these html pages by using iframe in the main page?

Comment: @ngsiolei Yes i have tried this and it does work. But Chrome seems to dislike this approach as the streams clip out of the iframe. It would also be nicer to keep it all in one document.

Comment: Is the `SncViewer.js` allowed to be changed? you could namespace those within the JavaScript itself.

Comment: @MackieeE Thanks for the tip, I hadn't even thought of that. Sadly, I only have read access on the device.

Comment: @stevanov I'll be brutally honest, that my answer is an idea & untested! - not 100% if it would work, may have to delete if it doesn't =)

Comment: What about using 2 `iframes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guilty for using jQuery here, also I've chosen `$(window).load` over `$(document).on('ready')` for this - furthermore it's untested!

```
$(window).load(function() {
    /**
     *  Array of IPs to load
     *  Empty Cameras = {} object 
     *  for Internal name-spacing.
    **/
    var Ips = ["192.168.1.10:80", "192.168.1.20:80"], 
        Suffix = "/jsv/SncViewer.js",
        Cameras = {};

    /** 
     *  For each IP, get script from
     *  IP Array, Keep the saved variable/SNC
     *  within Camera.camX.
    **/
    for( var x = 0; x < Ips.length; x++ ) {
       $.getScript({
           url: "http://"+ Ips[x] + Suffix +"",
           success: function( data ) {
               //May be data.writeViewer..!
               Cameras['cam'+ x +''] = 
                  SNC.writeViewer({sz:'4',ptz:'1',fps:'15',iPS:'1'});
           } 
       });     
    }
});

//Expected Output.
Cameras = {
    cam1 : //SNC Obj,
    cam2 : //SNC Obj
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, with a little modification it's working now. I didn't have any experience in javascript/jQuerry so i took a little longer than I should have.

Comment: Awesome =] You're always welcome to ask for anything else! Was it the `SNC.writeViewer` part you had to change?

Comment: Stevanov, do you have a copy of your finished code I could view somewhere? I have a similar issue with my Sony cameras and I am struggling with the above code. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would build a javascript file which will call the scripts using ajax. And load them one by one.