# How to specify which external JS file to use when calling function

Tags: javascript

I have to load two javascript files from the same company. These javascript files are different and contain different functions, but they use the same namespace (the company's name). I have both files included in my php file and when I try to create an object specified in one of the external js in my internal js code it searches for the object in the other js file so I get an error saying the function does not exist. When I comment out the other external file include, my code works. How do I force my internal js to look for the function in a specific external js file?

Comment: The answer to this question - [HTML multiple Javascript alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357774/html-multiple-javascript-alias) - might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you alias the other function to another variable?

e.g:

```
<script src='functions1.js'></script>
<script>
  var function1 = myCompany.someFunction
</script>
<script src='functions2.js'></script>
<script>
  var function2 = myCompany.someFunction
</script>
```